# Integral of product of $h_{x_{i}}(x)$ and $h_{x_{j}}(x)$, where $h_{c}(x) = \min(c,x)'$

Tags: integration, machine-learning

I am trying to integrate the product of  $h_{x_{i}}(x)$ and $h_{x_{j}}(x)$, where $ h_{c}(x) = \min(c,x)'$ as follows:

$$
h_{c}(x) = [\min(c,x)]'
$$

$$
\int_0^\infty h_{x_{i}}(x)h_{x_{j}}(x)\,\mathrm dx = \min(x_{i},x_{j})
$$

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you express $h_c(x)$ differently? What is $h_c(x)$ for $x<c$? And for $x>c$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $ h_{c}(x)=[x <= c] $ I assume this would give a vector of all values of x smalller than c

Comment: $$h_c(x) =\begin{cases} 1 & x< c\\0 &x > c\end{cases}$$So $$h_{x_i}(x) h_{x_j}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x< \min(x_i,x_j)\\0 &x > \min(x_i,x_j)\end{cases}$$